# How to copy existing gitlab project to new, but without any code - only it's settings?

Tags: gitlab

We have GitLab 12.4.0-ee and I've searched every settings tab, but didn't found anything relevant.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Premium plan, you can use [Custom instance-level project templates](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/admin_area/custom_project_templates.html)

Create a group and under this group, create a project with all settings you want. Then [configure](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/admin_area/custom_project_templates.html#configuring) the group to be the template source for the entire GitLab instance.

When you create a [new project](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/gitlab-basics/create-project.html#custom-project-templates-premium), navigate to `Create from template`, select the `Instance` tab and click on `Use template` button.